# Bounded operator, why does exist smallest such M that $ \|Lv\|_Y \le M \|v\|_X.\, \, $?

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations

[Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_operator), that

> In functional analysis, a branch of mathematics, a bounded linear
>   operator is a linear transformation $L$ between normed vector spaces $X$
>   and $Y$ for which the ratio of the norm of $L(v)$ to that of $v$ is bounded
>   by the same number, over all non-zero vectors $v$ in $X$. In other words,
>   there exists some $M > 0$ such that for all $v$ in $X$
>
> $$     \|Lv\|_Y \le M \|v\|_X. $$
>
> The smallest such $M$ is called the operator norm $ \|L\|_{\mathrm{op}} \, $
>   of $L$.

How do we know that smallest $M$ always exists? How can someone prove that it is impossible for the set of values of $M$ to be $(a,\infty)$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$, so smallest constant $M$ always exists?

Also, why we need to have $M > 0$? If we would take zero map, then for all $v$ in $X$ we would have

$$  \|Lv\|_Y = 0 $$

so $ M = 0 $. Why such a linear operator is not bounded? Is  $M > 0$ condition somehow important?

Comment: If $L$ is the zero map then *any* $M>0$ does the job, so such a linear operator *is* bounded. When we say *the smallest such* $M$, we mean $M=\inf\frac{\|Lv\|_y}{\|v\|_X}$ where the infimum is taken over all the $v\in V\backslash\{0\}$. Since this is the infimum of a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ bounded below (by $0$ for example), we know it exists and that it is a finite positive number. Now this infimum might be attained or not, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157436/bounded-operator-that-does-not-attain-its-norm) for example.