# Equivalent statements for $\Vert A\Vert=\inf\{\alpha\in\mathbb R:\Vert Av\Vert\leq\alpha\Vert v\Vert\ \forall v\in V\}$

Tags: linear-transformations

If a linear map $A\colon$ is bounded, its operator norm is defined as follows:
$$
\Vert A\Vert=\inf\{\alpha\in\mathbb R:\Vert Av\Vert\leq\alpha\Vert v\Vert\ \forall v\in V\}.
$$
My book says this is equivalent with the following two expressions:
\begin{align}
\Vert A\Vert=\min\{\alpha\in\mathbb R:\Vert Av\Vert\leq\alpha\Vert v\Vert\ \forall v\in V\}&& (1)\\
\Vert A\Vert=\sup_{\substack v\in V\\\Vert v\Vert\leq 1}\Vert Av\Vert&& (2)
\end{align}

I'm able to show the first equivalence: We know that $A$ is continuous. Therefore it attains a maximum. That means that the $\alpha\in\mathbb R$, for which $\Vert Av\Vert\leq\alpha\Vert v_{max}\Vert$, is the infimum we're looking for, and since it's attained, it's a minimum.

However, I was wondering, for the second equivalence, is it also possible to use $\Vert v\Vert=1$, instead of $\Vert v\Vert\leq1$? And is it also correct to use the maximum instead of the supremum?

Comment: @uniquesolution The vector for which $A$ attains its maximum.

Comment: Such a vector need not exist --

Comment: @uniquesolution Then why can we speak of the minimum? The linear map is bounded, therefore continuous. I thought that that meant that the linear map attains a minimum/maximum.

Comment: Because the infimum is taken over a set of real numbers bounded above by the norm of the operator and below by zero, and so the minimum is attained.

Comment: @uniquesolution But we need this set to be closed to conclude that the infimum is attained? And therefore we have to use the continuity of the linear map I'd guess.

Comment: Ok. Here is a formal argument. Consider the set $S=\{\alpha: ||Av||\leq\alpha||v||\,\forall v\}$. By definition, the infimum equals $||A||$. So if we can show that $||Av||\leq ||A|| ||v||$ for all $v$ then $||A||$ is also the minimum. However, were this not so, there would be some $v$ such that $||Av||>||A|| ||v||$, but then we could find some $\alpha$ in $S$ sufficiently close to $||A||$ which would give us a contradiction. Can you fill in the details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed possible to take the supremum over $||x||=1$. Indeed, if $0<||x||<1$  and $Ax\neq 0$ then clearly $||A(\frac{x}{||x||})||>||Ax||$, so the supremum of $||Ax||$ over $||x||=1$ will give the norm. In general, it is not possible to replace the sup by max, because if the space is infinite dimensional then the unit ball is not compact, and so the supremum need not be attainted. You can find [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157436/bounded-operator-that-does-not-attain-its-norm) examples of bounded operators that do not attain their norm.