# Continuity and upper bound for transformations

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations

Let $X$ be a normed vector space and $T: X \to Y$ a linear transformation in $X$, we define $\mu = \inf \{ M > 0 ; \| T(u) \|_Y \le M \| u \|_X \forall u \in X \}$.

If $T(u) = 0 \; \forall u$ that is always true because $0 \le M \|u\| \; \forall u$, since $M$ is always positive and $\| \cdot \|$ is always positive.

Can I say:

$\mu = 0 \implies T \equiv 0$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bounded operator that does not attain its norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157436/bounded-operator-that-does-not-attain-its-norm)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2178109/equivalent-statements-for-vert-a-vert-inf-alpha-in-mathbb-r-vert-av-vert-l?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope a proof by contradiction can help the OP to understand better the problem.

Assume that $T \not\equiv 0$.  There exists $u_0 \neq 0$ in $X$ such that $Tu_0 \neq 0$ in $Y$.  Take
$$M_0 = \frac{\lVert Tu_0 \rVert_Y}{2\lVert u_0 \rVert_X}.$$
Observe that $M_0 > 0$.  Using the hypothesis that $\mu = 0$ and role of $\mu$ as an *infimum*, there exists a positive number $M < M_0$ satisfying the condition inside the bracket.  That is,
$$\| T(u) \|_Y \le M \| u \|_X \forall u \in X.$$
Choose $u = u_0$ and recall the fact that $M < M_0$.
$$\| T(u_0) \|_Y \le M \| u_0 \|_X < M_0 \| u_0 \|_X < \frac12\| T(u_0) \|_Y.$$
Recalling the *assumption* that $Tu_0\neq0$, we divide its norm (which is *positive*) to derive a contraction.  This finish the proof.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that $X$ is a normed vector space and $T$ is a linear operator. I am right? If yes:

from the definition it follows that

$\| T(u) \|_Y \le \mu \| u \|_X$ for all $u \in X$. If $\mu=0$ , then $T(u)=0  \; \forall u \in X $.

Hence $T \equiv 0$ if $\mu=0$.