# Is there any guarantee that a norm one operator, $T$ will attain its norm at some extreme point?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

I am studying about extreme points and extreme operators. I have a question regarding norm one operators. For a finite dimensional Banach space $X$, using Hahn-Banach theorem we know that the set
$$M_T=\{x\in S_X:\|Tx\|=\|T\|\}, T\in B(X)$$
is non-empty. Can we gurantee that for a norm one operator, $T$, $M_T$ will contain at least one extreme point of the unit ball, $B_X$? A detail explanation will be very much helpful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since you're interested in the finite dimensional case, the answer is "yes". See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/157440/655547) to a related question. In the infinite dimensional case, the answer is "no" (see the same answer).

Comment: The solution linked in the previous comment explains why $M_T$ is a *nonempty* subset of the unit sphere of $X$, but not why $M_T$ contains an *extreme point* of $B_X$. But this is stated e.g. as part of Lemma 1.5 of A. Mal, K. Pal, and S. Dey, *Characterization of extreme contractions through k−smoothness of operators*, https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.15318, where it is deduced as a result of a more general statement about reflexive Banach spaces (Lemma 3.1 of P. Wojcik, *Birkhoff Orthogonality in Classical M-Ideals,* https://doi.org/10.1017/S1446788716000537).

Comment: @leslietownes thank you for your suggestion. It was really a helpful one. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assume that $X\ne \{0\}$.

Take $x$ with $\|x\|\le1$ such that $\|Tx\|= \|T\|$. Then there is $f\in X^*$ with $\|f\|\le1$ and $f(Tx)= \|Tx\|$.

In addition, if $\|y\|\le1$ then
$$
f(Ty) \le \|f\| \cdot \|T\| \cdot \|y\| \le \|T\|.
$$
Define the hyperplane $H$ by
$$
H = \{y \in X: \ f(Ty) = \|T\|\}.
$$
Then the unit ball $B_X$ is on one side of the hyperplane $H$ (due to the above inequality). In addition $x\in H \cap B_X$.
Then it is easy to check that $H \cap B_X$ is a closed face of $B_X$, hence it is compact and has an extreme point. This extreme point is also an extreme point of $B_X$. (This argument is part of the proof of the Krein-Milman theorem.)

The finite-dimensionality is only used to argue compactness of $H \cap B_X$. I think the argument also works in reflexive Banach spaces (where one uses weak compactness).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. This was beyond my imagination. I will try to understand it.